# MS Azure sends Notification to only 10 devices

Tags: azure, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I am Using Azure Notification hub when sending push notifications to GCM and APN what I notice on the production it is only send to the first 10 registered devices and other new register device cant receive messages despite it is already registered on GCM .   what i need is to send to all registered devices and they are round 600 devices.

public class Notifications
    {
        public static Notifications Instance = new Notifications();

```
    public NotificationHubClient Hub { get; set; }

    private Notifications()
    {
        string NotificationHubConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotificationHubConnectionString"];

        string NotificationHubPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotificationHubPath"];

        Hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(NotificationHubConnectionString, NotificationHubPath, false);
    }



    public static async void SendNotificationAsync(string Message, string Type, string ID, string Date, string Summery, string Location, string Risk)
    {

        string to_tag = Type.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        try
        {
            var notif = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"" + Message + "\",\"type\":\"" + Type + "\",\"ID\":\"" + ID + "\",\"Date\":\"" + Date + "\",\"Summery\":\"" + Summery + "\",\"Risk\":\"" + Risk + "\",\"Location\":\"" + Location + "\"" + ", \"sound\" : \"default\"}}";
            var outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notif);

            string msg = string.Format("This Notification: " + Message + " has been delivered to this number [" + outcome.Success.ToString() + "] of android Mobiles");
            Logger.LogMessage(msg, EventLogEntryType.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = string.Format("Coudn't send notification to android mobiles");
            Logger.LogMessage(msg, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            Logger.LogException(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);

        }
        try
        {
            var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + Message + "\",\"type\":\"" + Type + "\",\"ID\":\"" + ID + "\",\"Date\":\"" + Date + "\",\"Summery\":\"" + Summery + "\",\"Risk\":\"" + Risk + "\",\"location\":\"" + Location + "\" " + ", \"sound\" : \"default\"}}";

            var outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert, to_tag);
            string msg = string.Format("This Notification: " + Message + " has been delivered to this number ["+ outcome.Success.ToString() +"] of IOS Mobiles");
            Logger.LogMessage(msg, EventLogEntryType.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = string.Format("Coudn't send notification to IOS mobiles");
            Logger.LogMessage(msg, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            Logger.LogException(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the built-in testing tool in the Notification Hubs blade in the Azure Portal or Visual Studio.

**This is by design** - a test notification from there will go to 10 random devices. You will need to have a real backend sending notifications in order to propagate to all devices that are registered.

Details are outlined [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-diagnosing/).

> Note that the use of this property is heavily throttled and so you
>   must only use this in dev/test environment with limited set of
>   registrations. We only send debug notifications to 10 devices. We also
>   have a limit of processing debug sends to be 10 per minute.

Check for this line:

```
bool enableTestSend = true;
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(connString, hubName, enableTestSend);
```

In order to deliver for more than 10 devices, you need to make sure that you are not using [EnableTestSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt587768.aspx).

Comment: i am sending from .net backend , is there any configuration should i use

Comment: Are you following a sample or did you write your own?

Comment: i am using the sample

Comment: Let me know how it goes, would be more than happy to help.

Comment: sure , i appreciate ur fast response and solution

Comment: Hi Den i updated the post with part of the code would you please check i disabled the parameter u had mentioned before and set it to false. appreciate ur help

Comment: Then how do we send the test notification to the specific test device. I can do it with postman but not with the visual studio interface. And adding the "to" field to the load does nothing